# How to use 'make' to compile c file in OS X?

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal

I have installed Xcode 5, OS X 10.9. 
In terminal gcc -v shows that is is configured.
How to use 'make' to compile 'c' file?
For example, my file is ex1.c?

Comment: Do you have a makefile that targets your c file to be compiled? Make is a command that calls a makefile to automatically compile and sometimes run your script..it does not (as far as I know) just magically work without a makefile.

Comment: Do I need some extra app to do it (except from Xcode)?